# Are PS1 games compatible on the latest version of PS3 - as of May 2012?

Tags: ps3, ps1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you play PlayStation 1 games on the PlayStation 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/428/can-you-play-playstation-1-games-on-the-playstation-3)

I want to buy some old PS1 games online and was told most are compatible.
Am interested in the superhero games for my son.  Spiderman 1, 2, & 3, Batman and Robin,
X-men, Marvel Heroes, Star Wars and the Lego series of games for PS1.
Anyone know if these are still compatible? or does it make more sense to buy them from sony's PlayStation Network?
Thanks

Comment: Hey, welcome to GSE. This question has been asked already: [Can you play PlayStation 1 games on the PlayStation 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/428/can-you-play-playstation-1-games-on-the-playstation-3)

Comment: If a game is available on the Playstation Network for download, its disc counterpart should probably work on the console as well.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the lastest version of the PS3." That could either be the software updates automatically delivered through the Playstation Network, or the most recent version of the PS3 manufactured (as in, the PS3 Slim).

Regardless, the Playstation network has a psOne classics library from which you can purchase games that are guaranteed to work on your system. I've heard that the PS3 Slim has *very* limited backwards compatibility in comparison to the older model. The best advice I can give you is that before you start buying physical copies of these older games, check the psOne classics on the Playstation Network.